# Why use the `var` keyword in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Every tutorial and code snippet I'm looking at while learning the framework all use `var` for their declarations, including [the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html).

Preface, I'm just starting to learn Vue, so I know very little about it, but haven't found an answer yet.

Same with other like assuming property name:

```
new Vue({
  data: data
})
```

vs.

```
new Vue({
  data
})
```

Am I wrong in assuming that ES6's `const` and `let` should be standard? Is there a reason to use `var` for Vue.js? Is there an issue with ES6?

Comment: I would assume that its because that you would need an ES6 compatible compiler for the interpreter to handle those things. Vue wants to get people working JS straight in without necessary setup. Whether this is what they intended is another story.

Comment: doesnt Vue leverage babel and if so, doesnt it get converted to the correct syntax anway

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do the docs use `var` and avoid ES6 features? I'd say to support *lowest common denominator*, ie, worst browser.

Since Vue can be included as a plain old `<script>` tag (UMD / global, no build system) and supports all [ES5-compliant browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) (IE9+), they keep the documentation consistent.

---

Use whatever you...

1. Feel comfortable using, and
2. Is supported by the target production environment

   - your build system (if you're using one) can help transpile ES6 code to a lower language level

Answer (score 1):

Besides the *lowest common denominator* arguments I would like to point that `var` and `let` have different semantics.

When using `var` variables are function scoped and they get hoisted. When using `let` they are blocked scoped and they don't get hoisted.

So even if `let` and `const` are standard they (probably) won't replace `var` any time soon.